# Average data which comes out of a Crystal Report formula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have a formula in my Group Header which looks like the following:

```
if count({Removals.rpid},{Removals.r-ixservice}) <> 0 then 
( sum ({@SIT - Count},{Removals.r-ixservice}) / count({Removals.rpid},{Removals.r-ixservice}) * 100)

else 0;
```

This works perfectly in that it spits out a % number based on the fields above. However, in the Report Footer I would like to average all the data generated by the above formula and spit it out so that if in the report this formula had been on 3 lines saying 90-80-70, then in the footer it would say 70.

I tried using Average({@Formulaname})but Crystal just says "This field cannot be summarized".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its already a summarized formula so you can't summarize it again..suggested option would be use arrays and summarize.

Try this

Use the formula in group header and supress

```
    Shared Numbervar array store;

    if count({Removals.rpid},{Removals.r-ixservice}) <> 0 then 
    store:=store+( sum ({@SIT - Count},{Removals.r-ixservice}) / count({Removals.rpid},{Removals.r-ixservice}) * 100)

    else store:=store+0;
1
```

Now in report footer

```
Shared Numbervar Array store;
Local Numbervar i;
Local numbervar final;

For i:=1 to Ubound(store) do
(
final:=final+store[i];
);

Final/Ubound(store);
```

Comment: Hi Siva,

When I tried this the first portion in the group header formula Crystal  popped up with the error "This array must be subscripted. For example: Array [i].